# How to let the coroutine stop and print the error message

Tags: python, debugging, python-asyncio

I have two coroutines, where co_2 have some bugs in it, when I run it, co_2 just stop printing and co_1 will keep running with no error message. How can I let the program stop on any error message/warning and print the message so I can fix it.

```
import asyncio

async def co_1():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        print('co1111111111111111111111111111111111111')

async def co_2():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        print('co222222222222222222222222222222222222 ')
        a=numpy.zeros(4,4) # bug, didn't import numpy
        pritn(a) # bug typo

async def await_list():
    await asyncio.wait([co_1(),co_2()])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(await_list())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `asyncio.wait()` returns future objects which encapsulate the results of running both coroutines. It is perfectly legitimate for one coroutine to raise an exception and the other one to return a value. Since you requested to wait for both coroutines to finish (the default), the await in `await_list` will keep waiting for `co_1`.

The simplest fix is to change:

```
await asyncio.wait([co_1(),co_2()])
```

to:

```
await asyncio.gather(co_1(), co_2())
```

Since [`gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) provides direct results rather than indirect future objects, it will stop at first exception and propagate it to the awaiter. The exception will bubble up to top-level where it will be picked up by the interpreter, and reported along with a sensible traceback.